# Ignoring library.zip in py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe

I need to have an executable file (.exe) which takes some parameters from a file which can be configured by the user depending on his/her need.  Since i have created scripts in python, i have used py2exe to create that executable. Though i could place a configurable file called ***settings.dat*** as data file and use it to customize, i feel it would be better if the configurable file is python file (lets say ***settings.py***) and use it import the variables declared in it.

So settings.py shouldn't be included in library.zip and i would like it to be included as it is and make it configurable by user.  Is this possible ?

Is there any way to avoid creating library.zip and just put all dependency files in a sub folder ? (In this case i can just put settings.py inside it, since settings.pyc is derived from it any changes made to settings.py will get reflected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to avoid creating library.zip and just put all
>   dependency files in a sub folder ?

Yes, set the `skip_archive` option to `True`.

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions

EDIT: The pyc files are placed in the same folder where the zip file would have been. The `zipfile` keyword controls the path to the zip. This puts the files in subfolder `foo`:

```
setup(  
    ...

    zipfile="foo/bar.zip", 
    options={"py2exe": {"skip_archive": True}})
```

Comment: Hi Janne Karila, yes i can use skip_archive, but am unable to put the files in a subfolder, it just copies all the files to the folder where the required executable exits, but i dont want this to happen.  I need the dependencies in a seperate sub folder.  Is there any way or workaround ?

Comment: Hi Janne Karila, thanks ! It works !!. I have also enabled 'bundle_files' before so it gave me permission denied error. Now it works as i expected. :-)