# Python: installer with py2exe and project with OpenOPC module

Tags: python, installation, py2exe, win32com

I searched for how can I produce a installer for my Python project.
I found a good alternative, that is the py2exe module. This is used on a setup.py.

But my project uses a com server with win32com module into the OpenOPC module.
For this reason, after I produce a standalone directorie with the exe file, this executable does not works, returning this exception:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'C:\\Users\\(project directory)\\dist\\lib\\shared.zip\\win32com\\gen_py\\__init__.py'
```

I searched more about this and found this page:
http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndWin32com

This page teaches a 'model' for setup.py to include a com server as module.
But I did not understand this 'model'.
It is generic for all com servers and do not introduce where should I include the OpenOPC module.
I have tried some ways to use this model like:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys

class Target:
    def __init__(self):
        self.version = version
        self.company_name = author
        self.copyright = license_
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.modules = ['C:\\OpenOPC\\src\\OpenOPC.py']
        self.create_exe = True
        self.create_dll = False


sys.argv.append('py2exe')
setup(name=name,
      version=version,
      author=author,
      author_email=author_email,
      maintainer=maintainer,
      maintainer_email=maintainer_email,
      url=url,
      license=license_,
      description=description,
      long_description=long_description,
      keywords=keywords,
      platforms=platforms,
      console=console, zipfile=zipfile,
      com_server=[Target()])
```

Unfortunately this did not work.
I tried to put some others files or directories on modules into Target class constructor.
It seems that I have to put the OpenOPC module here if it is not in other point.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "didn't work"?  Do you get a different error when using this example?  I'm pretty sure I have used COM in scripts I've deployed - I'll have to see if I can find an example I can post.

Comment: The last error using this example is simply do not find the module. That is it. And I tried put some other files and directores from OpenOPC directory in C disk.

Comment: I tried like this guy and worked:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002097/ignoring-library-zip-in-py2exe

Answer (score 0):

I did:

```
sys.argv.append('py2exe')
setup(name=name,
      version=version,
      author=author,
      author_email=author_email,
      maintainer=maintainer,
      maintainer_email=maintainer_email,
      url=url,
      license=license_,
      description=description,
      long_description=long_description,
      keywords=keywords,
      platforms=platforms,
      console=console, zipfile=zipfile,
      options=options)
```

where

```
options = {'py2exe': {'packages': ['win32com']}}
```

That is it. Worked. And my application have a OPC client and not OPC server. If it would had a OPC server (COM server), maybe it would have been even more difficult.